# Ubuntu 20.04 to Windows 10 WIFI via crossover ethernet

Tags: wireless, sharing, crossover

How do I share my Windows 10 WIFI on my PC with my Ubuntu 20.04 PC via crossover from one pc to the other?

- Windows 10: Realtek RTL8723BS SDIO 802.11n (internet connection shared)
- Windows 10: Ethernet Realtek USB FE Family Controller
- crossover cat6 cable
- Ubuntu 20.04: Intel i218LM Gigabit Ethernet

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.  The ip settings on both windows and ubuntu should be set to automatic and the ethernet cards should be connected with a regular ethernet (not crossover)  One just needs to select Both your wifi and ethernet in windows 10 adapter settings, and bridge the connections.